# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile

Tags: docker, selenium, maven

maven build failure

docker file:
[this is my dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gav0X.png)

selenium code:
[using selenium 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR5LI.png)

error:
[getting this error while creating image from dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbO0O.png)

Comment: Your docker file uses JDK8 as base image but your code needs JDK17...

Comment: thanks! that error has gone. now its unable to open the browser. i am getting session not created exception